# ACDC sings of a 21-gun-salute, but I hear less shots

Tags: lyrics

I was always wondering whether in ACDC’s *For Those About to Rock (We Salute You)*, if really 21 salutes are shot. I count less.

Here is the part after the first section, with gun shots in shown in parentheses:

> We're just a battery for hire with a guitar fire
> Ready and aimed at you
> Pick up your balls and load up your cannon
> For a twenty-one gun salute
>
> For those about to rock, fire (1) (we salute you)
> Oh, for those about to rock (2) (we salute you)
> Those about to rock, fire (3) (we salute you)
> Fire (4), we salute you [solo starts]
> We salute you, come on
>
> For those about to rock, we salute you
> For (5) those about to rock, we salute you
> For (6) those about to rock, we salute you
> For (7) those about to rock, we salute you
>
> Shoot (8), shoot (9)
> Shoot (10), shoot (11)
>
> Oh, for those who give, for those who take
> Doing your time and those on the rank
> We salute you, yeah
> We salute you
> We salute you
> We salute you
>
> (12)
> (13)
> (14)
> (15)
> (16)
> Fire
> (17)

Comment: For the record, a 21-gun salute is done with an array of 7 guns, fired three times.

Answer (score 0):

I count the same as you for the album version of the song.

I only count 13 shots the [“Official Video” on YouTube](https://youtu.be/8fPf6L0XNvM?si=kWqFfdvJIgcryd4P); I can’t hear what you’ve labeled as (5), (6), (7) or (16). But there are two cannons and probably a few simultaneous shots which I only counted once.

In [this transcription](https://guitaralliance.com/instant-song-library-download/Instant%20Song%20Library%20PDF/A-F/A/acdc-for_those_about_to_rock_we.pdf) there are only 10 shots.